# magento paymant after customer approve the product

Tags: magento

I am working on a sticker development site in magento. The customer will choose any of the templates from the listed template, which is the produc. After customer choose a sticker template customer will add the design suggestion as a file or comments in the order. After checkout(without doing payment) admin will work on the design and upload for customer approval. The customer will do the payment only after he  has approve the design upload by admin.

So in magento i need to do the payment only after the customer approve the design we are not doint the payment at the time of checkout. Is there any option like this in magento. I am using magento 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "preorder" function in Magento and set the product avaible for customer after the customer approval. The preorder part is a magento feature. You need to work on the avaible per customer product function.
Let me know if it was usefull.
filippo

Comment: Pre order can be useful customer to order a product which is out of stock currently in cart. But in our case the one option for the customer is pay later. If he is acception the design and template he can purchase the product at that time itself using the credit card or via check payment. Also the pre order options are not in default magento. Its an extension which has to be paid.